# Is there a way to tell that the program is in process of throwing an exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

**Short version of my question**

There's an object of type A allocated on the stack. In its destructor ~A(), is there a way to tell if the destructor is getting called because an exception was thrown and the stack is unwinding, or is it just because the scope where it was defined ended 'naturally'? I tried checking whether `std::current_exception` is not null, doesn't work.

**Longer version**

I have an old API I have to support:

```
void MyApi()
{
    try
    {
        MyTimeTracker mtt;
        //do API stuff
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //handle exception
    }
}
```

If `API stuff` throws an exception, it indicates the API failure, otherwise it indicates success. MyTimeTracker checks how much time the execution of `API stuff` takes - it measures the start time in the constructor and the end time in the destructor and reports it to the database.

Now I want it to also report whether the API call was successful. Is there a way to tell that in the destructor?

I am not allowed to allocate it outside of the first `try` block, as the entire API code must be in a try block. I can put `API stuff` into a separate try block inside the first one, and then rethrow, but that looks ugly.

I tried checking `std::current_exception` in the destructor, but it's null, even when we're in process of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard portable way to detect the status of stack unwinding like you describe.

But there is an easier solution.  Add a boolean member to `MyTimeTracker`, set it if the API is successful, and then check it in the destructor.

```
MyTimeTracker::MyTimeTracker()
{
    ...
    success = false;
}

MyTimeTracker::~MyTimeTracker()
{
    ...
    if (!success) {
        ... 
    }
}

void MyApi()
{
    try
    {
        MyTimeTracker mtt;
        //do API stuff
        mtt.success = true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        //handle exception
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

> the main reason for doing all that is to report back the error code, which sits on the exception.

Then you have to resort to a second `try/catch` to get the error code, store it in the `mtt` object to act on in the destructor, and rethrow:

```
MyTimeTracker::MyTimeTracker()
{
    ...
    errCode = 0;
}

MyTimeTracker::~MyTimeTracker()
{
    ...
    if (errCode != 0) {
        ... 
    }
}

void MyApi()
{
    try
    {
        MyTimeTracker mtt;
        try
        {
            //do API stuff
        }
        catch (const the_api_error &e)
        {
            mtt.errCode = ...; // error code from e... 
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        //handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes obvious and simple is so elegant.

Comment: This won't work in my case. I didn't want to get into details, but the main reason for doing all that is to report back the error code, which sits on the exception. Alas. Thanks though.

Comment: @remy-lebeau seems that `std::uncaught_exception` was designed exactly for this purpose: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception. However it doesn't let you see what the exception actually is

Comment: @Valentin: I've never heard of `std::uncaught_exception()` before.  But like you said, you don't have access to the actual exception, so you are going to have to actually catch it so you can copy the data from it